# What is the runtime cost of Swift's casts?

Tags: swift, casting, time-complexity, overhead

What are the different runtime costs incurred by the following type casts?

1. **Numeric cast of constant**, e.g.:

   ```
   let f = 0.1 as CGFloat
   ```

   I'd imagine this has zero runtime cost.
2. **Numeric cast of runtime value**, e.g.:

   ```
   let f = someDoubleValue as CGFloat
   ```

   I'd imagine this has an extremely small runtime cost.
3. **Upcast**, e.g.:

   ```
   let dict: [String: Int] = ...
   let anyObj = dict as AnyObject
   ```

   I'd expect this to have zero runtime cost.
4. **Failable Downcast**, e.g.:

   ```
   let anyObj: AnyObject = ...
   if let str = anyObj as? String { ... }
   ```

   I'd expect this to have a runtime cost proportional to the number of classes in the hierarchy of the dynamic type of `anyObj`.
5. **Forced Downcast**, e.g.:

   ```
   let anyObj: AnyObject = ...
   let str = anyObj as! String
   ```

   Maybe the cost for a forced downcast is slightly lower?
6. **Forced Downcast of collection**, e.g.:

   ```
   let dates: [AnyObject] = ...
   for date in dates as! [NSDate] { ... }
   ```

   What happens here — especially when `dates` comes from an `NSArray`? Is the runtime cost of this cast proportional to the number of its elements? What if I cast to a more complex collection type like `[String: [String: [Int]]]` — is the whole collection traversed to make sure all its elements and subelements conform to this cast?

For each of the first four cases, are my assertions true?

Comment: I guess there are too many possible and correct answers to your many questions. E.g. your no. 2: an optimizer can detect how `f` is used and if the machine architecture fits it can just use `someDoubleValue` directly as being a `Double` while in other cases it must copy the value into some extra memory. In case it will need memory at all as it might keep it all in the registers. If performance in such cases is in question: create a benchmark.

Comment: As I understand, #3 is not realy upcast example, because swift dictionary is a structure, and when you "cast" it to AnyObject, swift actually creates NSDictionary. This must be same for Int -> NSNumber, String -> NSString and others

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- It is O(1) (almost 0) if it is obviously castable(like numeric casting and upcasting): case 1, 2, 3.
- For other non-collection castings, it is obviously O(1): case 4, 5.
- For collection downcastings:

  - `as?` is O(n) because element type checking is performed eagerly.
  - Native forced downcasting is O(1) because element type checking is deferred: case 6.
  - Bridged forced downcasting(`NSArray as! [NSDate]`) is O(n) because element type checking is performed eagerly.
  - Nested collections are recursively casted so you just apply the above rules recursively.

Sources:

1. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/Casting.cpp
2. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ArrayCast.swift
3. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb

Comment: Great answer, thanks for looking into this that thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that the runtime cost of protocol typecast is horrific. I tried to look at it in disassembly view and simply lost track of what's happening. So a line like this:

```
(self as! SomeProtocol).someMethod()
```

results in retain/release (which involve memory barriers), then there's a call to the old good `objc_msgSend()` (!) but not related to `someMethod()`, I presume because one of `self` or `SomeProtocol` are derived from `class`, and then a very very long chain of function calls with some loops involved. Like I said I lost patience trying to debug this single line of code in disassembly view.

While protocols are a really nice abstraction, they should be used sparingly in performance critical code.